# passing the variable to another page in post method

Tags: php, jquery

I have 2 pages one is chart page and another one is detail page. On click the chart bar I get the value and pass it to post method and get the response from another page.

**Chart page:**

```
$('.bar').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'detail',

        dataType: 'json',
        data: filtervalues_rightclick,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {
            url_value = 'http://domain/detailview';
            $url = url_value + response.query_string;
            window.open($url, "_blank");
        }
    });
});
```

Get the value from the detail view. I want to retail the post response in second page (detail_view) even in page refresh. So I have passed the value in the URL. Is there any other way without passing parameter in the URL?

Comment: another ajax???

Comment: if response is only query string than you can just set cookies in your browser and use that.

Comment: a dirty way can be submitting a form with action="detailView.php" and get the information there from $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set cookie in the AJAX request like below and the use it on other page:

```
    $('.bar').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'detail',

        dataType: 'json',
        data: filtervalues_rightclick,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response) {
            url_value = 'http://domain/detailview';
            $url = url_value + response.query_string;
             setCookie('pageurl', url, 1); 
        }
    });
});

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```